# It's possible to execute css on javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change CSS when i click on picture. I do somes search and i find the function `onclick="js function"` but i don't know how to execute the css. Here is the css i need to execute on the function `onclick=""`

```
.all:hover {
perspective: 1000px;
transition: all 1.3s ease-in;
transform: perspective(10000px) rotateX(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this with JS? Just add that rule to your CSS file.

Comment: Andy how did i do that?

Comment: So many things to explain... Basically, you dont get CSS "executed". You should give your element the given class so styles get applied. You dont have to "execute" anything. Maybe using other selectors like `:active`?

Answer (score 0):

this is a way for what you want:

1- Give an ID to your picture

2- you should create a class in your css file and give it these "hover" styles.

3- you should create a js function and call it with "onclick" picture event. in this example, I called my function, "myFunction".

4- create a script tag and write this function for what you want:

```
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("your picture ID");
  element.classList.add("Put the class you just created in your css file");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "give it these "hover" styles."??

Comment: For example, if you want to give some css styles to your picture, you can create a class with your css styles, and give the class to your picture. right? for example your picture has a 2px red border, and you'll create a class with a 1px solid blue border. If you give the class to your picture, now your pic has a 1px blue border. You can create a class with the styles you want to execute on every element in your html doc (for example your pic). And finally add your class that you just made by your JS script to every element you want (with your onclick event). @JeanBobo